# Synchronizing storyboards in WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I have two storyboards in XAML (Blend), each with 10 identical keyframes. Based on a databinding, I want to be able to switch between the two storyboards. The Storyboards both target the same object -- a .png image. What i can't figure out is this:

How to sync the storyboards so that if Storyboard1 is on keyframe 5, and the data binding changes to 'switch' to Storyboard2, the current keyframe in Storyboard1 can be detected, and then Storyboard 2 can start on the next keyframe, in this case keyframe 6.

Can anyone tell me how to do this and display the XAML and/or C# code to achieve it?